# how to Updating nested array of objects in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

I have a problem when trying to update my data in MongoDB. My data looks like this:

```js
{
  "_id": "65eca2dae5a8eefadc76efa5",
  "user": "65d384b711bf4920f77d4430",
  "notplace": [],
  "months": [
    {
      "MonthNumber": "3",
      "total": 5,
      "half": 18,
      "all": [
        {
          "lunch": {
            "hours": 0,
            "minutes": 0
          },
          "start": "15:00",
          "end": "20:00",
          "des": "",
          "date": "Sat Mar 09 2024 18:56:42 GMT+0100 (Central European Standard Time)",
          "total": 5,
          "half": 0,
          "_id": "65eca2dae5a8eefadc76efa6"
        },
        {
          "lunch": {
            "hours": 0,
            "minutes": 0
          },
          "start": "20:00",
          "end": "23:01",
          "des": "",
          "date": "Sat Mar 09 2024 18:56:52 GMT+0100 (Central European Standard Time)",
          "total": 3,
          "half": 1,
          "_id": "65eca2e4e5a8eefadc76efaa"
        },
        {
          "lunch": {
            "hours": 0,
            "minutes": 0
          },
          "start": "12:00",
          "end": "14:08",
          "des": "",
          "date": "Sat Mar 09 2024 18:57:01 GMT+0100 (Central European Standard Time)",
          "total": 2,
          "half": 8,
          "_id": "65eca2ede5a8eefadc76efc1"
        }
      ],
      "_id": "65eca382e5a8eefadc76eff7"
    },
    {
      "MonthNumber": "4",
      "total": 2,
      "half": 40,
      "all": [
        {
          "lunch": {
            "hours": 0,
            "minutes": 0
          },
          "start": "19:11",
          "end": "20:03",
          "des": "",
          "date": "Sat Mar 09 2024 19:11:47 GMT+0100 (Central European Standard Time)",
          "total": 0,
          "half": 52,
          "_id": "65eca663948b8c2b99971270"
        },
        {
          "lunch": {
            "hours": 0,
            "minutes": 0
          },
          "start": "21:16",
          "end": "23:04",
          "des": "",
          "date": "Sat Mar 09 2024 19:12:03 GMT+0100 (Central European Standard Time)",
          "total": 1,
          "half": 48,
          "_id": "65eca674948b8c2b99971288"
        }
      ],
      "_id": "65eca6ddb3b9c5e9d0ac9510"
    }
  ],
  "createdAt": "2024-03-09T17:56:42.922Z",
  "updatedAt": "2024-03-09T18:17:21.635Z",
  "__v": 4
}
```

I saw some comments and solutions but it didn't work.

I tried every way but I couldn't.

```js
mahmoud.updateOne(
  {
    user: req.params.id,
      months: {
        $elemMatch: {
          all: {
            $elemMatch: {
              _id: '65eca674948b8c2b99971288'
            }
          }
        }
      }
  },
  {
    $set : {
      'months.$[].all.$[lastElemt].start': '11:11',
      'months.$[].all.$[lastElemt].end': '11:11',
    }
  },
  {
    arrayFilters: [
      { 'lastElemt._id': '65e58e0763942e14988d9332' }
    ],
      "multi": true
  }
)
```